invalid criteria for IN drupal to wp migration
civi 5.73.3 on both sites. New wp civi install imported data only from Drupal minus 5 recommended to leave. Also didn't import any non-core extensions. user id 1 for wp and uf-match. Works before I import but after import throws the "Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [undefined: invalid criteria for IN thrown in /home/xxxx/public_html/763/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php on line 138 for url "/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM" . No civi log as it never launches. No clues in browser tools and not sure how else to troubleshoot
